# Getting the value of a tag using its classname in HTML

Tags: php, html

I know how to get the value based on id and tags while parsing HTML. But I don't know how to get the value based on `classname`. This is what I have tried:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName($identifier);

foreach ($data as $v) 
{
    $value[] = $v->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just tried to get elements by tagname. What you need to do is:-

```
1.Get all the elements by TagName.
2. Now take the classname from the tagname if exists.
3.Compare the classname wit ur input classname, if exists print that data.
```

Try out this , worked for me:-

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$new_data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
        $matched = array();

        //echo $data->nodeValue;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $new_data->length; $i++) {

            if (isset($new_data->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue)) {
                $classname = $new_data->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue;
                if ($classname == $identifier) {
                    $matched[] = $new_data->item($i)->nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($matched);
```

Comment: Looks interesting will try...